# An abstract signature for "without" some type

Tags: scala, mixins

I want a method of a type to return the type it is mixed into. E.g., something in the spirit of the following:

```
trait A {
  def withoutA: this.type without A
}
```

So in case of type `A with B with C`, the method `withoutA` would have a signature `B with C`, in case of `A with D` - just `D`.

Is this achievable and how if it is?

Here's an example of how it could be used:

```
trait Limit {
  def limit(a: Int): this.type without Limit
}
trait Offset {
  def offset(a: Int): this.type without Offset
}
val sqlBuilder = new Limit with Offset { ... }
sqlBuilder.limit(2).offset(4) // valid code
sqlBuilder.offset(4).limit(2) // valid code
sqlBuilder.limit(2).limit(4) // invalid code
```

Comment: What would you need this feature for? (Just interested to know what you think this would be useful for).

Comment: @Jesper Not easy to describe. A composite builder, which consequently loses methods with application of each one. This provides static guarantees that only the methods which make sense are available.

Comment: That can be done with the type-safe builder pattern. As you're probably finding out, it's not hard to get at-least-once invocation for the mandatory parameters but it's hard to to get exactly once. I recommend Jim McBeath's three-part series of blogs on solving this problem: http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2009/09/type-safe-builder-in-scala-using-church.html

Answer (score 1):

A stab in the dark here, but the type Negation [as defined by shapeless](http://www.chuusai.com/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/) might work here.

```
type ¬[A] = A => Nothing

trait A {
  def withoutA: this.type with ¬[A]
}
```

Without access to a REPL right now, I haven't had the chance to test this though.  I'd *also* be interested to know the use-case.

UPDATE:

If what you really want is a builder that progressively reduces the operations available as you use them, then phantom types and the type-safe builder pattern come to the rescue:

http://james-iry.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/phantom-types-in-haskell-and-scala.html

http://blog.rafaelferreira.net/2008/07/type-safe-builder-pattern-in-scala.html

You might want to update the title of the question as well, so it's easier for others to find :)

Comment: The blogpost is a great read. The code you presented, however, doesn't solve the problem, since the compiler sees the type of `(new A with B {...}).withoutA` as `Nothing`, and so doesn't see any members of `B` on that type.

Comment: So, basically, an implicit conversion parameterized on type-level. A very nice idea. Thanks. However I still am looking for an answer to the actual question.

Comment: I'm a software craftsman here!  It's my *Job* to answer the **actual** requirement and not simply what the users thought to ask :)